# how to add a character before every line?

Tags: linux

I have a big txt file where I want to add a fasta symbol before every line as a new line. I tried with sed, I can add it before the line but not as a new line.

I have file like this

```
AAAAAAAAAACA
AAAAAAAAAACTTAT
AAAAAAAAACATGTGACTA
AAAAAAAAACTTATTCTTTTT
AAAAAAAACATGTGACT
```

And I want something like this

```
>
AAAAAAAAAACA
>
AAAAAAAAAACTTAT
>
AAAAAAAAACATGTGACTA
>
AAAAAAAAACTTATTCTTTTT
>
AAAAAAAACATGTGACT
```

Thanks,

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: What is your original problem description, assignment or exercise? What have you tried yourself to solve the problem? And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the sed command like this:

```
sed 's/^/>\n/g' file.txt> file2.txt
```

Comment: sed 's/^/>\n/g' file.txt> file2.txt : Extra dot deleted first letter from the line followed by fasta symbol.

Comment: @GabrieleRenzini - good one. Could you also describe it and edit the post?

Answer (score 0):

**SED**

```sh
# If you want to edit the file in-place
sed -i -e 's/^/prefix/' file

# If you want to create a new file
sed -e 's/^/prefix/' file > file.new
```

*How?*

- simple format is : `sed 's/x/y/g'` - with this, `x` will be replaced with `y`
- Use `-e` to add the script to the command (better to use it always) (More described here ([click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33157/what-is-the-purpose-of-e-in-sed-command)))
- Use `-i` for input in the same file

**AWK**

```sh
awk '{print ">\n"$0}' file >> newFile
```

*How?*

- Simple format : `awk '{print $0}' file` will print whole lines as it is.
- Then just add the prefix you need "xyz\n"\

**WHILE LOOP**

```sh
while read line ; 
    do 
        echo -e ">\n$line" ; 
    done < file
```

- With this you can play around your each lines
- If you want to do for particular lines alone use the file input as `done < <(cat file | grep "TT")`
- If you want to add some condition, `if line contains... then.. echo "prefix"$line` is also possible.
- Note: it removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters (spaces and tabs, or any whitespace characters present in IFS)

---

*Note:*

If `prefix` contains `/`, you can use any other character not in `prefix`, or
escape the `/`, so the `sed` command becomes

```sh
's#^#/opt/workdir#'
# or
's/^/\/opt\/workdir/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$0=">\n"$0' <(echo -e "foo\nbar")
>
foo
>
bar

# change inplace 

$ cat file
foo
bar
baz

$ awk -i inplace '$0=">\n"$0' file
$ cat file
>
foo
>
bar
>
baz
```